React Native Expo - Network Request Failed
I have an Expo app where I'm trying to make HTTP requests to a Node.js server running on my local network. I use the IP address of my computer (e.g. 192.168.29.1) and not localhost while making http request. When testing the app using Expo's development server, everything works fine. However, when I build the app into an APK and install it on my mobile device, it's unable to connect to the Node.js server.
I make following fetch request and i get error in catch block in alert message as

Network request failed

import {Alert} from "react-native"
const apiEndPoint = "http://192.168.29.1:3050"

async function Login(){
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${apiEndPoint}/user/login`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: "username",
        password: "password",
      }),
    });
    if (response.ok) {
      Alert.alert("success", "login successful");
    } 
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    Alert.alert("error", error.message + `${apiEndPoint}/user/login`);
  }
}

The mobile is also connected to same network but has different ip address 192.168.29.38. What should i do to solve this issue. What IP address should i use to make fetch request

You compare the development server (192.168.29.1) with your mobile, but that is confusing, because your mobile is a client and should be compared with the browser on your computer. Both clients talk to the same server 192.168.29.1, which must be running when you test on your mobile.

The android and Ios systems do not send request just for secured server or http so you have to deploy your server and get the https://.... link of the server app, then  connect the built mobile app (APK) to your deployed server
